# Webbrowser converts double quotes to %2522

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

As explained in the title, whatever I do, I can't get webbrowser to open the URL I want it to open.

I tried escaping the double quotes with \

I tried using %22 in the URL instead of "

No matter what, the end URL ends up effectively turning " into %2522

I know that %25 represents %, which means, somehow " is being turned into %22 first and then the % in that is being turned into %25. Makes no sense, I don't know why it would get processed twice anyway.

Example URL (what I get when I print the variable in python):

https://domain.com/do?q=item:(("abc")+OR+("def")+OR+("ghj"))

What webbrowser opens in Chrome:

https://domain.com/do?q=item:((%2522abc%2522)+OR+(%2522def%2522)+OR+(%2522ghj%2522))

Comment: Got the same problem here. It seems to be a bug in the Python URL handling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is URL encoding twice. `%2522` is a double encoding of `"` as the encoding of `%` is `%25`.

```
> decodeURIComponent('%2522')
"%22"
> decodeURIComponent('%22')
"\""
```

Comment: The thing is I'm not processing the URL at all. It comes straight from a list and gets appended a string. 

<!-- language-all: lang-pyton -->
`urls = appscript.app('Google Chrome').windows.tabs.URL()

fresh = [item for sublist in urls for item in sublist]`